# CMake + Ninja : how to implement incremental compilation under the path of different source directories

Tags: cmake, ninja

Every time I get a different source directory, and I have a fixed build directory. Every time I will run `cmake /path/to/project` and run ninja. It will report an error : `Make Error: The source "/path1/to/project/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/path2/to/project/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache. Re-run cmake with a different source directory.`

So what I did was manually change the options related to the path of project in the CMakeCache.txt. The result is that it will compile the project from scratch every time instead of incrementally compiling, So is there any feasible way to achieve incremental compilation or in this case it is impossible to achieve incremental compilation ？

Comment: Why are you running cmake multiple times?

Comment: @sweenish Because the path of project is changed. So I should rerun cmake /new_path/to/project, isn't it ? And every time the project is update (the source files have some update)

Comment: If you are constantly changing the path, you shouldn't be surprised that you get errors. Cmake tells you what to do in that case: delete everything it created and run it from scratch. You do **not** run it again if all you did was update a source file. You run ninja again.

Comment: Why are you constantly moving the source directory? Is `ccache` not an option?

Comment: @AlexReinking yes I have tried `ccache`, but it doesn't work.  Moving the source directory because

Comment: @sweenish Even if they are in different paths, I just run ninja again ? I mean I updated some source files in another project path, in this case, I think I must run cmake first ?

Comment: @AlexReinking sry, I forgot it. Beacause it runs in the git CI, every some time it will create a new temporary directory...

Answer (score 0):

Mount the source directory always to a same constant absolute location. On Linux, you could use mount namespaces, for example use `proot`.

```
proot -b /path/to/project:/work -w /work cmake -B builddir -S .
proot -b /path/to/project:/work -w /work cmake --build builddir
```